# Eigenspaces of commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

According to wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices, there is a characteristic for commuting matrices such that:
If A has distinct eigenvalues, and A and B commute, then A's eigenvectors are B's eigenvectors.
How to prove this statement?